# python draw multigraph

Tags: python, graph, drawing

I try to draw multigraph in Python using graphviz.

For now I can draw usual graphs in Python somehow like:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G=pgv.AGraph()
G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.layout()
G.add_edge('a','b','first')
G.add_edge('a','b','second')
sorted(G.edges(keys=True)) 
G.draw('file.png')
```

And I get on the output:

[image]

But actually I want get multigraph, i.e.

[image]

But documentation stays that it should differentiate :

[image]

I have no idea about drawing multigraph but not just graph.

Thanks for any help.

**Addition:**

it seems that there are no yet such libraries in python that can do it, so I did it using Wolfram Mathematica. But question is still opened.

**Addition**

Now working code looks so:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
G=pgv.AGraph(strict=False)
G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.layout()
G.add_edge('a','b','first')
G.add_edge('a','b','second')
sorted(G.edges(keys=True)) 
G.draw('file.png')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation you quoted says, you need to specify `strict=False` when creating a multi-edge graph. Since you didn't do this your graph doesn't support parallel edges.

Comment: yeeeeeees! thank you , if it was possible  I'd press vote up button endless times