# How to draw multiple edges between same set of nodes in PyGraphviz?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, graphviz, pygraphviz

Whenever I try to draw multiple edges between two same nodes, Pygraphviz only considers the latest edge. Is there any way to bypass this?

**Example Code:**

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
A = pgv.AGraph()
A.add_node(1, style='filled')
A.add_node(2, style='filled')
A.add_edge(1, 2, style='filled', label='aron')
A.add_edge(1, 2, style='filled', label='jessica')
A.add_edge(1, 2, style='filled', label='diana')
A.layout()
A.draw('simple.png', prog='dot')
```

**Graph generated:**
[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12829435/1290420). Answer: `A = pgv.AGraph(strict=False)`

Comment: Thanks for notifying!